# What is the 2015 alternative of imbinarize in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, threshold

I need to use [`imbinarize(I, T)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html?s_tid=doc_ta). I am using Matlab 2015a.

Which function can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[im2bw](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) is the equivalent in older Matlab versions that you are looking for.